# Django Heroku Application Error. Whats wrongs?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am getting an application error while running my django app on heroku. Here are the results from heroku logs:

```
2017-04-08T17:24:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user anmol.gulati9513@gmail.com
2017-04-08T17:25:11.732420+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f4ef15f by user anmol.gulati9513@gmail.com
2017-04-08T17:25:11.732420+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user anmol.gulati9513@gmail.com
2017-04-08T17:25:11.987358+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user anmol.gulati9513@gmail.com
2017-04-08T17:24:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-04-08T17:25:12.354075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-04-08T17:25:18.683488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --pythonpath expense_manager expense_manager.wsgi --log-file -`
2017-04-08T17:25:20.881565+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-04-08T17:25:20.880602+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-08T17:25:20.868145+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2017-04-08T17:25:20.728492+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-04-08T17:25:20.729017+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:38551 (4)
2017-04-08T17:25:20.729116+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-04-08T17:25:20.732466+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736689+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736693+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736694+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736695+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736696+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736697+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736699+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736697+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736698+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736700+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736699+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736701+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736701+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736703+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736702+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736703+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736704+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named 'expense_manager.wsgi'
2017-04-08T17:25:20.736798+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2017-04-08T17:25:20.780458+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-04-08T17:25:20.780489+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2017-04-08T17:25:25.419069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --pythonpath expense_manager expense_manager.wsgi --log-file -`
2017-04-08T17:25:27.653789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2017-04-08T17:25:27.664966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-08T17:25:27.418329+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428032+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428038+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named 'expense_manager.wsgi'
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465402+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.418976+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428033+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428182+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465402+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2017-04-08T17:25:27.422342+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428033+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2017-04-08T17:25:27.460499+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465403+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.568119+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2017-04-08T17:25:27.418827+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3650 (4)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428033+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465397+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465403+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428028+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428034+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465398+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465404+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428030+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428034+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465399+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465404+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428031+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428036+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465401+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465405+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428032+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428036+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465401+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465408+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named 'expense_manager.wsgi'
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428030+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428035+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465400+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465404+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428031+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2017-04-08T17:25:27.428035+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465400+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465405+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2017-04-08T17:25:27.465511+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2017-04-08T17:25:27.568035+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-08 17:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-04-08T17:26:52.783836+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=expense-manager-django.herokuapp.com request_id=1d751f3f-b874-44d7-88f1-39996099aefa fwd="182.71.131.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-04-08T17:26:53.380252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=expense-manager-django.herokuapp.com request_id=ffc9e5e0-040d-4eb7-ace9-261c42044a47 fwd="182.71.131.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please help! I am new to deploying projects using heroku.I really don't understand these logs, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

```
├── accounts
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├── db.sqlite3
├── expense
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── expense_manager
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── home.html
    └── welcome.html
```

Here, I have posted the tree as well

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be using that `--python-path` parameter.

Comment: Now it says Failed to find application: 'expense_manager' @DanielRoseman

Comment: What does your file tree look like? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19671818/6085135

Comment: w  -  expense_manager(main project folder contains all the apps and manage.py file etc)  requirements.txt  Procfile  runtime.txt @bren

Comment: This is the expected file structure https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started maybe you can show us your file tree with `tree -L 2` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree

Comment: I have posted the tree @bren

Comment: `gunicorn --workers=1 --pythonpath expense_manager wsgi` Try this on your machine before bouncing another change off Heroku...  if it doesn't work you may need to reconfigure your folder structure and/or imports.

Comment: It says: [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18929 @bren

Comment: Can you test out the app at `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to see if it's working as expected, it should say something like `[INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: PS you'll also need to swap out sqlite but that's a different issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/31395988/6085135

Comment: Yes, It is working fine. @bren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your Procfile try:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath expense_manager wsgi
```

This is essentially the equivalent of how you'd run:

```
python expense_manager/wsgi.py
```

Gunicorn's `--pythonpath` argument allows you to specify a directory, package name and even module. Like this:

```
gunicorn --pythonpath <directory> <package>.<module>
```

Comment: Where's your `.git` folder located? Run `ls -a` Also maybe doublecheck it's not `python-path`

Comment: Dude you are a saviour

Comment: woohoo thanks! now let me forget about all the time i wasted before i found this!