# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

[image][image: staticfiles]when i run git push heroku master it says that my STATIC_ROOT is improperly configured (ERROR:raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path".). I have set my STATIC_ROOT just as shown in a video tutuorial.

> settings.py

```
import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '###############################'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://mypytalk.herokuapp.com/']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pytalk.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pytalk.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

.gitignore

```
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
pip-wheel-metadata/
>>>>>>> 661353800061e4584535573f7e8b813cb01040c2
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
<<<<<<< HEAD
cover/
=======
>>>>>>> 661353800061e4584535573f7e8b813cb01040c2

# Translations
*.mo
*.pot

# Django stuff:
*.log
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# PyBuilder
<<<<<<< HEAD
.pybuilder/
=======
>>>>>>> 661353800061e4584535573f7e8b813cb01040c2
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
<<<<<<< HEAD
#   For a library or package, you might want to ignore these files since the code is
#   intended to run in multiple environments; otherwise, check them in:
# .python-version
=======
.python-version
>>>>>>> 661353800061e4584535573f7e8b813cb01040c2

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/
<<<<<<< HEAD

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# Cython debug symbols
cython_debug/

/.idea/
.idea/workspace.xml
=======
>>>>>>> 661353800061e4584535573f7e8b813cb01040c2
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What tutorial are you following? Note that you've got merge conflicts in your `.gitignore` (the `<<<<<`/`>>>>>` sections), you should tidy it up.

Comment: i am following a tutorial by correy schaffer. How can i do that . i have added some scrren shots can u please check them

Comment: You still haven't shown the full error message when you run `git push heroku master`. I don't think you've included enough information for us to help you. If you link to the specific part of the tutorial where you got stuck then it might help, but I don't think anyone is going to start searching for *correy schaffer tutorials* and try to track down where you might be stuck.

Comment: The merge conflicts in `.gitignore` are a side issue, it's unrelated to your static files issue. The file shouldn't contain `<<<<<` / `>>>>>` or `======` equal lines, so you could remove them. The merge conflict might mean you end up with missing/duplicate lines. Because it's only a `.gitignore` file that doesn't matter too much, but you should try to avoid merge conflicts because they can break your code.

Comment: i added the error screenshot kinda confused where the error can be

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, copy and paste the error. I'm not sure why you are using `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'` -- usually on Heroku the suggestion would be to use whitenoise. Make sure you are following your tutorial instructions for static files exactly.

Comment: One other suggestion is to check that you don't have a different settings file (e.g. `settings_production.py` that is changing `STATIC_ROOT` to something else.

Comment: Finally, note that using `sqlite3` won't work on Heroku - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395856/django-deploying-an-application-on-heroku-with-sqlite3-as-the-database) for more info.

Comment: oh ok i will try adding whitenoise and see if it works i am very thankful for your time thanks for the help man

Answer (score 4):

You need to name these variables like this (and remember to create the corresponding folders):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'), ]
```

Answer (score -1):

As you added STATIC ROOT into your settings.py.
You also have to add static directory path into root directory's urls.py file, where you have your settings.py file.

```
from django.views.static import serve

path('static/<path:path>/', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, }),
```