# django heroku deployment postgres config

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

this is my first time deploying a Django app to Heroku I followed the the [Django Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

the app is deployed successfully but when I open the app I got this error :

```
relation "products_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ory"."image", "products_category"."catogory" FROM "products_...
```

this is  the changes I did to my settings.py after reading the documentation :

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

the database configuration  is still running with sqlite3:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   }
  }
```

so what do I need to change in my setting  to deploy my apps properly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395856/django-deploying-an-application-on-heroku-with-sqlite3-as-the-database

Answer (score 1):

first of all, in your dashboard, Heroku app go to settings and get rid of this DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC conf.

in your settings.py add

```
STATIC_ROOT  = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

create a directory called staticfiles, and add smth to it (eg. tmp.txt) just to make sure that git add . will include this directory.
Push everything to Heroku and then use these commands:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations

heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you  I will try that  and tell you if it works :)

Comment: TBH I'm not sure if it will work with your with your settings from heroku tutorial, but what I always do when I upload Django to heroku is follow this tutorial: https://www.codementor.io/@jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4 it is a little bit outdated (eg. stuff with whitenoise, read http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0 and you will get through it) and additionally to it I will do this part from the answer

Comment: thanks  I  will create another app and  use the tutorial   to see if  it works

Answer (score 0):

try

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: still the same error :django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "products_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ory"."image", "products_category"."catogory" FROM "products_...

Comment: when you deployed  to Heroku, did you use this command: Heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1

Comment: That's not good, I also had a hard time uploading my first project to Heroku. What I learned that you shouldn't disable collectstatic, instead try to follow my other answer(i will post it in a sec)