# How to get users back after deploying Django App to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I've deployed a React/Django app on Heroku and when I tried to login, I found out none of the users I had locally were present on the deployed App. I thought it could be that it didn't migrate so I did

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Got no migrations to apply so I now have an app without an Admin account and I don't know how I could create one nor access the one I had locally

Ps: I'm using Sqlite database on it

Comment: SQLite does not go well with heroku. You might want to move to postgres or use another service. Check this: [Django: Deploying an application on Heroku with sqlite3 as the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395856/django-deploying-an-application-on-heroku-with-sqlite3-as-the-database)

Comment: Thank you I'll switch to Postgres