# how to copy my my production app data into my local host app

Tags: django, sqlite, django-database

I deployed an app on Heroku and I have same app in my local machine now i want to copy all my deployed app data on my local app to so is there any way to do it anyway that will be very helpful because I don't know how to copy all my production data and paste it into my local machine I am using default sqlite3 Django default database

Comment: if you are using SQLite on Heroku, that is a bad idea - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395856/django-deploying-an-application-on-heroku-with-sqlite3-as-the-database)

Comment: @JPG right now i testing my application by the way i will take your advice and move to PostgreSQL thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using [heroku-cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) otherwise install it on your local machine.
then run `heroku run bash` in the heroku-cli
now you can run `django-admin dumpdata` and copy the data dump, then save it in a local JSON file and import it to your local python app with [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)

You can run bash from the **Heroku dashboard** (not cli) but it is not possible to copy data from there, another workaround is to upload db.sqlite to dropbox or to some other convenient cloud storage from the Heroku dashboard with the `run bash` method.

Comment: i am using cli but when i run django-admin dumpdata it throws error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: how about python manage.py dumpdata